# Trouble computing integral with scipy quad

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics, integral

I'm trying to compute the following definite integral:

Integral I want to compute:

[image: Integral I want to compute]

where `rho_ch` is

[image: rho_ch]

and

`a = 3.66 * 10^(-15) m` (in meters)

`b = 0.54 * 10^(-15) m`

and `rho_0 = 1.23 * 10^(-35) C/m^3`.

When I compute it, I get something of the order of 10^(-61), but I believe it should be something closer to 1.

I take the upper limit of the integral to 10^(-10) because the integral should have converged by then. My guess is that the problem has do with overflow in the rho_ch function, although I tried a fix for that, but it didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.constants import *
from scipy import integrate

Z_t = 20
a = 1.07*40**(1/3)
b = 0.54
rho_0 = 0.077*e
X_0 = np.array([rho_0, a, b])*10**(-15)
E = 250*10**(6)*e
p_sq = (E/c)**2-(m_e*c)**2
beta_sq = 1-(1/(E/(m_e*c**2))**2)
theta = np.pi/6

def q(theta):
    return 2*np.sqrt(p_sq*np.sin(theta/2)**2)

def F_quad(theta, X):
    return 4*np.pi*hbar/(Z_t*e*q(theta))*integrate.quad(integrand2, 0, 10**(-10), args=(theta, X))[0]

integrand2 = lambda r, theta, X: r*X[0]/(1+np.exp((r-X[1])/X[2]))*np.sin(q(theta)*r/hbar) if (r-X[1])/X[2] <= 600 else 0
```

Comment: It looks like `hbar` is not defined in your code (in return of `F_quad(theta, X)`)?

Comment: Hey, hbar is the reduced Planck constant from the scipy.constants library. It should be defined.

Comment: `quad` returns two values: the estimate of the integral, and an estimate of the error in that integral.  What is the second value in your case?

Comment: In order for your code to be a [minimal, *reproducible* example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you should include the call of `F_quad` that demonstrates the issue.  Is it `F_quad(theta, X_0)`?

Comment: Before you spend time trying to figure out if `quad` is doing something wrong, make a few plots of `integrand2(r, theta, X_0)` against `r`, and verify that it looks like you expect.  I tried, and I see a maximum of about 2.79e-50 occurring at r ≈ 2.65e-15.  If that is accurate, there is no way the integral can be close to 1.

Comment: It's also possible that I just got the integrand formula wrong or messed up my units somewhere...

Comment: Hey, when I look only at the integral part of F_quad, the error is of the order 10^(-145), which is of the same order as the first value. Yes plotting is a good idea... But I have a hard time interpreting the graph from a physics point of view (this is a sub problem of trying to calculate the nucleus radius of an atom). The integral is supposed to be a correction to a value, so that's why I thought it should be close to 1 but yes clearly it isn't here.

Comment: Update: problem solved, I had just done a stupid unit error. The integral gets close to 1 now.